# How to get values 1-52 for number week using DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MYSQL.

To get 1-52 I am using YEARWEEK as follows

`SELECT YEARWEEK('1999-01-01') ==> 199852`

But I need to use DATE_FORMAT to get the same results, so far I was using the next format with no luck

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1999-01-01','%Y%v') ==> 199953`

Comment: Did you try %u? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: That goes from 0 to 53 weeks I need 1 to 52.

Comment: Years can have 53 weeks... So either 0...52, or 1...53, but not 1..52 always.

Comment: When I try your first query I get `199852`, not `199952`.

Comment: Depending on when week 1 starts (might be in the "old" year) years can go up to 53 weeks -this is culture dependend:   in Germany the 31st of December 2012 (a monday) is in week 1 of 2013

Comment: @trincot. The function YEARWEEK always returns from 1-52, I just need the equivalent with DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Not true: `select yearweek('2007-01-01') == 53`

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Can you explain why you can't work with `YEARWEEK` although you say it gives you the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1999-01-01','%X%V');
```

`%X` is variation of `%Y` that determines the year based on week mode 2, and `%V` returns the week number using that mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that is what I was looking for, I appreciate your help.

Comment: One more thing @Barmar. Is it posible return just `19991` instead of `199901` with `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1999-01-05','%X%V');`?

Comment: I don't think so. All the week number formats return 2 digits.

Comment: Ok, I will reformat it after query execution in the app. Thanks.

Comment: Let's compile all this great information into some kind of easily accessible online documentation.

Comment: The documentation is confusing. The description of `YEARWEEK()` says it defaults to mode = 0 with one argument, but the description of `DATE_FORMAT` says to use `%U` for mode 0, but that didn't give the correct answer.